# Addition of two spins

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

In the addition of two spins, $S_1$ and $S_2$ show that operators $S_1^2$,$S_2^2$,$S_{1z}$,$S_{2z}$ can have common eigenkets, however, operators $S^2$ and $S_{1z}$ cannot have common eigenkets for $S=S_1+S_2$.
For this question, will it be sufficient to use commutation relation alone to show that if they commute, they have common eigenkets and if they don't, they cannot have common eigenkets ? 
Also, if $S_1^2$,$S_2^2$,$S_{1z}$,$S_{2z}$ can have common eigenkets, then how to find the common eigenkets?

Comment: How exactly it is important the two spins are being added? In the first question, indeed it is sufficient to consider the commutativity of the two operators. But for the second point, we are given two commuting operators spin operators S1 and S2, and total spin operator Si sirely commutes with its spin-z projection. So the last point seems rather trivial - just consider product basis of spin eigenbasis for each of S1 and S2 operators - there the addition does not play a role, as you are looking for eigenbasis for Si, not S.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are asking for. A set of operators is simultaneously diagonalizable ("has common eigenkets") if and only if they all commute with each other. What's the question about that?